# Laravel 7. Attempt method return false

Tags: php, laravel

I hope my english is good enough to explain my problem. I'm working with laravel 7, and I'm trying to implement my own AuthController, because I can't use migrations and I can't use a table 'users' because I have a db implemented. I've read all the documentation of laravel about authentication and spent days reading a lot of posts with this problem, and I tried everything but still does not work. The problem is with the attempt method. My register method is working fine, but I can't login, actually I tried to put manually the data(that's why credentials are commented) to find the problem but I don't know why is not working

My Regsiter method.

```
public function storeUser(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request);
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:administradores,ADMIN_Correo',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required',
        ]);

        Administrador::create([
            'ADMIN_Nombre' => $request->name,
            'ADMIN_Correo' => $request->email,
            'ADMIN_Contrasena' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        //return redirect('home');
    }
```

My Login method.

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        /*$request->validate([
            'ADMIN_Correo' => 'required|string|email',
            'ADMIN_Contrasena' => 'required|string',
        ]);*/

        //$credentials = $request->only('ADMIN_Correo', 'ADMIN_Contrasena');
 
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['ADMIN_Correo' => 'edwin2@gmail.com
        ','ADMIN_Contrasena' => '12345678'])) {
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        }else{
            echo 'error';
        }

        //return redirect('login')->with('error', 'Oppes! You have entered invalid credentials');
    }
```

My config/auth.php file

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ]
    ],
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Administrador::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Administrador::class,
         ],
    ],
```

My Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Administrador extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'administradores';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ADMIN_Id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = true;
    protected $fillable = ['ADMIN_Nombre','ADMIN_Correo','ADMIN_Contrasena'];
    protected $guard = 'admin';

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->ADMIN_Contrasena;
    }

}
```

**NOTES** The field for password:(ADMIN_Contrasena) is varchar 255